# Order ListView by boolean and double values

Tags: android, listview, sorting, collections, boolean

I have a ListView which is currently in ascending order based on a double value that each element of the listview has.

List

```
public class CollegeList extends ListActivity {

ArrayList<CollegeItem> collegeLists=new ArrayList<CollegeItem>();
ArrayList<String> nameList = new ArrayList<String>();

Comparator<CollegeItem> compareByScoreDistance = new Comparator<CollegeItem>(){
    public int compare(CollegeItem a, CollegeItem b){
        return Double.compare(a.getScoreDistance(), b.getScoreDistance());
    }
};


CollegeItem michigan = new CollegeItem(3.79,30,2020,"University of Michigan","Ann Arbor, Michigan");
CollegeItem berkeley = new CollegeItem(3.84,30,2040,"University of California Berkeley","Berkeley, California");
CollegeItem stanford = new CollegeItem(3.96,33,2215,"Stanford University","Stanford, California");


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    collegeLists.add(michigan);
    collegeLists.add(berkeley);
    collegeLists.add(stanford); 

    Collections.sort(collegeLists, compareByScoreDistance);

    for(CollegeItem collegeList : collegeLists){
        nameList.add(collegeList.getName());
    }

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(CollegeList.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, nameList));



}
private class CollegeItem {
private double gpa;
private int act;
private int sat;
private String name;
private String location;
private double score;
private double scoreDistance;

public CollegeItem(double gpa, int act, int sat, String name, String location){
    this.gpa = gpa;
    this.act = act;
    this.sat = sat;
    this.name = name;
    this.location = location;
    if(act/36.0>sat/2400.0){
        this.score = 0.6*gpa*25.0+0.4*(act/36.0)*100.0;
    }else{
        this.score = 0.6*gpa*25.0+0.4*(sat/2400.0)*100.0;
    }
    this.scoreDistance = Math.abs(this.score-MainActivity.scoreDouble)/MainActivity.scoreDouble;

}

public String getName(){
    return this.name;
}
public String getLocation(){
    return this.location;
}
public double getScoreDistance(){
    return this.scoreDistance;
}
}
}
```

In this case it is sorted by ascending the scoreDistance value. Now I would like for each of the college objects to have boolean parameters. For example, if a certain parameter is true, those colleges should come before those which are false, but withing the two groups, the ordering should still be based off of the scoreDistance value. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Write your comparator to first check for the boolean, then check for the double value if the booleans are the same for both items.

```
public int compare(CollegeItem a, CollegeItem b) {
    int result = Boolean.compare(a.getBoolean(), b.getBoolean());
    if (result == 0) {
        // boolean values the same
        result = Double.compare(a.getScoreDistance(), b.getScoreDistance());
    }
    return result;
}
```